AWS Kurento Install Problen accessing template bucket
I am following the instructions here to install Kurento on aws by using the cloud formation template.
Unfortunately I'm failing at the first step as I keep getting the following error.
An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the template. This could be due to the template not existing or insufficient permissions for the S3 bucket. Verify the template's existence and your permissions.
The S3 url in the instructions is
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws.kurento.org/KMS-Coturn-cfn-7.1.0.yaml
Anyone resolved this issue?
D.
I've tried googling for other options but not fond anything yet.

Having this same issue. Have you had any luck finding the right file? I was able to find this older one (KMS-Coturn-cfn-6.16.0.yaml) that's in the same S3 bucket.
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws.kurento.org/KMS-Coturn-cfn-6.16.0.yaml
